# Custom portlet.vm-templates by portlet-type?

Tags: templates, liferay, portlet, theming

Is there a way to provide an custom portlet.vm-template based on the portlet type in Liferay Portal 6.0.6?
Something like search-portlet.vm and sitemap-portlet.vm or does it have to specified in any XML config-files (in the portlet itself or in the theme)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of this being declarable, but you should be able to access `$portletDisplay.getId()` (or similar) in your template and continue from there.

However, by design you shouldn't add too much design to the portlets this way - you can also achieve a different look&feel through CSS, addressing the different portlets (all of them have specific classes based on their portlet-name/id)

The classic use for portlet.xml is to provide the repetitive decoration for *all* portlets, so having this uniformly provides a common look&feel for all of the portal.